# How to import a configurable product with it's associated simple products using a .csv file?

Tags: magento-1.9, import

How to import configurable products and it's associated products using a .csv file.

Is there a template which I can get? If so where? And also is there a guide I can follow to do it?

Comment: which magento version?

Comment: It's Magento ver. 1.9.3.2 @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

Default import profile allows to upload configurable products, but in my case (I have lots of associated products) it's really a nightmare.

It's better to use the

`<a href="http://mag-manager.com/free-download" title="Store Manager for Magento">import</a>`

tools that optimize configurable product creation, especially if you have multiple configurable attributes.

By the way Magento 1.9.3, as I have heard from community users, it